# Return the rows with different values in the next column

Tags: sql

I want to write a query that returns the rows that have 2 different values As an example:

This is the table I have - table name is `Deliveryschedulefruits`:

```
ContactId  Fruit
-----------------
45166      apple
45168      apple
45169      apple
45166       orange
```

The result should be:

```
 45166      apple
 45166      orange
```

I tried a few solutions on my own but I can not come up with the desired result:
This does not work. I feel it should

```
select  * 
from MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits 
where ContactId IN (select a.ContactId 
                    from MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits a
                    join MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits b On b.ContactId = a.ContactId 
                                                      And b.Fruit <> a.Fruit)
```

Please help me. I can not seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add what dbms are you using. mysql, sql server, postresSQL?

Also, what does this show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits.*
from(    
     select ContactId 
     from MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits
     group by ContactId 
     having count(*)>1
) as doubles
inner join MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits on MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits.ContactId=doubles.ContactId 
order by MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits.ContactId, Fruit
```

The subquery returns all the ids you want. And you can read the Fruit with those id.

What I think is wrong with your query is that it will return dublicates if you have more than 2 fruits per `contactID`. You need to use `distinct`. Like this.

```
select  * from MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits 
where ContactId IN (
      select distinct a.ContactId 
      from MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits a
      Join MOW_DeliveryScheduleFruits b
      ON b.ContactId = a.ContactId AND b.Fruit <> a.Fruit
)
```

Using `group by` is more efficient than an extra `join`.

Comment: Happy to help :D
Please upvote and accept the answers that help you. That way, the best answers go on top and can help other people that may have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `exists`:

```
select f.*
from fruits f
where exists (select 1
              from fruits f2
              where f2.contactid = f.contactid and f2.fruit <> f.fruit
             );
```

If you have a large table, this can make optimal use of an index on `(contactid, fruit)`.